# oracle 10 connection on arcgis 10, windows 7

Tags: oracle-dbms, arccatalog, windows-7

I have problem odbc connection on arcgis 10, oracle 10 and windows 7. odbc connection on windows, running well. but when arcgis conection via arcatalog, appear error "Test connection error because of an error in initializing provider. specific driver could not be loaded due to system error 5: acccess dedied. (oracle in OraClient10g_home1, D:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\client_1\BIN\SQORA32.DLL)."

anyone can help me. many thanks before.

regards, 
widi

Comment: A couple of questions. First, are you running 32 or 64 bit windows? Since Arcgis is not 64 bit, there may be some sort of conflict there. Next, are you running SDE or just regular Arcgis? Finally, were you able to connect in the past, but can't now?

Comment: firstly, make sure that you have installed 32 bit Oracle client. Secondly, can you connect to oracle from the 32 bit Datasources (found at C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\odbcad32.exe) ?

Comment: we running with windows 7 (64 bit). when conected ODBC from windows control panel, running well. but when ODBC conection from arccatalog, appear error "Test connection error because of an error in initializing provider. specific driver could not be loaded due to system error 5: acccess denied. (oracle in OraClient10g_home1, D:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\client_1\BIN\SQORA32.DLL)